# Dynamic array parsing in retrofit android

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

The Response to parse is below:
I tried to parse using POJO class structure like
public MatchFullCardResponse.data.card.now.recent_overs_str[] getRecent_overs_str() {
                                return recent_overs_str;
                            }

```
                        public void setRecent_overs_str(MatchFullCardResponse.data.card.now.recent_overs_str[] recent_overs_str) {
                            this.recent_overs_str = recent_overs_str;
                        }

                        @SerializedName("recent_overs_str")

                        recent_overs_str[] recent_overs_str;
                        public class recent_overs_str
                            {}
```

But getting error expexted Object but found array

recent_overs_str": [[6, ["b4", "r0", "r1", "r1", "r0", "r5"]], [5, ["r0", "r0", "r2", "r1", "e1,wd", "r1", "r0"]], [4, ["w", "w", "r0", "r1", "e1,lb", "e1,wd", "r0"]]], "balls": 36}

Not able to parse using POJO class.KIndly help me to creating the structure for the above dynamic response.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkxEQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way is to write your own JsonDeserializer since you have only values and no names for them it seems.

Comment: How to do that can you share the method body for that response

Comment: are you using gson for parsing?